# Sencha Touch - Incorrect version of Pullrefresh function being invoked

Tags: pull-to-refresh, sencha-touch-2.2

I am using `PullRefresh` in the following code, but it is not working in the build:

```
        xtype:'dataview',
        mode:'multi',
        plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                fetchLatest: function(plugin) {
                    var json = localStorage.getItem("JSON");
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method:'POST',
                        url:webservice_url,
                        params:{ params:json},
                        success:function (response) {
                            var storeobj = Ext.getStore('questions');
                            storeobj.sync();
                            storeobj.add(result.info.info);
                            storeobj.sync();
                        },
                        failure: function(res){
                            console.log('Failure');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        ],
```

What happens when I run the build is that the `fetchLatest` function of pullRefresh.js gets excecuted, instead of the above `fetchLatest` function.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem as yours, may be it's not a good idea to configure function 'fetchLatest'.

This might be a solution:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261763-PullRefresh-without-refreshFn&p=1007532#post1007532